# json request with angularjs

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

i'm looking to do a AJAX request whith json file but it's dont parsed.

My controller :

```
function troupesController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
 $http.get('js/data/troupes.json').success(function(data) {

     console.log(data);
     console.log(data.test);
     $scope.troupes = data;
});
```

}

App.js :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-carousel']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html'})
    .when('/about', {templateUrl: 'views/about.html'})
    .when('/batiments_troupes', {templateUrl: 'views/batiments_troupes.html'})
    .when('/troupes', {templateUrl: 'views/troupes.html', controller: 'troupesController'})
    .when('/unitee', {templateUrl: 'views/unitee.html'})
    .otherwise({ redirectTo:'/home'});
```

});

The json file :

```
{
'test':'toto;'
'troupes' : [
    {
        'name': 'Barbare', 
        'basic_image': 'troupes/barbare/base_Barbarian.png'
    }
]
```

};

And the result of console.lg is :

```
 {
'test':'toto;'
'troupes' : [
    {
        'name': 'Barbare', 
        'basic_image': 'troupes/barbare/base_Barbarian.png'
    }
]
```

};
undefined

Comment: JSLint says your JSON file is invalid, start there (double quotes!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

few corrections made in the JSON

```
 {
    "test":"toto",
    "troupes" : [
         {"name" : "Barbare",
          "basic_image" : "troupes/barbare/base_Barbarian.png"
         }
    ]
 }
```